# Python: global name 'maximum' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,300,500,600], 
                   'B':[100,200,300,400], 
                   'C':[1000,2000,3000,4000], 
                   'D':[1,4,5,6],
                   'E':[2,5,2,7]})
```

and when applying the pairwise maximum to any two columns, using

```
maximum(df.A,df.B)
```

I get an error saying

```
NameError: global name 'maximum' is not defined
```

I was under the impression that this error only occurred when using a variable that had not been assigned yet. However, the maximum function should work in numpy. I know I can just apply

```
df[['A','B']].apply(max)
```

but I am concerned as to the cause of the error. Why is it complaining about not having defined a reserved function keyword?

Comment: What would you like the output to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you miss "np." by any chance after importing numpy as np . Here is my output from my MacBook :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.maximum(df.A,df.B)
0    100
1    300
2    500
3    600
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP wanted... +1

Answer (score 1):

pandas alternative:

```
In [32]: df[['A','B']].max().max()
Out[32]: 600
```

step-by-step:

```
In [31]: df[['A','B']].max()
Out[31]:
A    600
B    400
dtype: int64
```

if you need a maximum per row:

```
In [35]: df[['A','B']].max(axis=1)
Out[35]:
0    100
1    300
2    500
3    600
dtype: int64
```